# Add infoWindow to a map marker using jQuery mobile, google maps API v3

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, jquery-ui-map

I have a simple script that adds a marker on a map when you click a button using jQuery mobile and the Google Maps API v3.  I want to add a basic infoWindow to that marker, so that when you click on it, it says "Hello World".

This seems like it should be very easy, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.  I'm adding markers like this

```js
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': chicago } );
```

and I can't seem to find any good examples where you also setup an infowindow when you also set up the marker.

Here is my code. If you save in the `jquery-ui-map-3.0-rc\demos\` directory, then all the paths will be correct.  When you click 'Add Some More Markers', a marker in the `chicago` location is added to the map. I want to be able to click on that marker and have an info window pop up that says "Hello World!".

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps - Google maps jQuery plugin</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/min/jquery.ui.map.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033,-87.6500523);
            var mobileDemo = { 'center': '41,-87', 'zoom': 7 };
            var cityList = [];

            function initialize()
            {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': mobileDemo.center, 'zoom': mobileDemo.zoom, 'disableDefaultUI':false });
            }


            $(document).ready(function() 
            {
                initialize();
                $('.add-markers').click(function() {
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': chicago } );
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQuery mobile with Google maps v3</a> examples</h1>
                <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="add-markers" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Add Some More Markers</a>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

If I change the code inside `$(document).ready(function()){}` to the following, the marker doesn't even show up anymore.

```js
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            initialize();
            $('.add-markers').click(function() {
                //$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': chicago, 'content': "Hello World!"} );
                $('#map_canvas').gmap({'callback': function() {
                    var self = this;
                    self.addMarker({'position': chicago }).click(function() {
                        self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': 'Hello World!' }, this);
                    });
                    }});
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have added the requested open info window. Please check the below code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps - Google maps jQuery plugin</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/min/jquery.ui.map.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033,-87.6500523),
            mobileDemo = { 'center': '41,-87', 'zoom': 7 };

            function initialize() {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': mobileDemo.center, 'zoom': mobileDemo.zoom, 'disableDefaultUI':false });
            }

            $(document).on("pageinit", "#basic-map", function() {
                initialize();
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.add-markers', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': chicago } ).click(function() {
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': 'Hello World!'}, this);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQuery mobile with Google maps v3</a> examples</h1>
                <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="add-markers" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Add Some More Markers</a>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

**Example without the jQuery-ui-maps plugin:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps - Google maps jQuery plugin</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var cityList = [
                ['Chicago', 41.850033, -87.6500523, 1],
                ['Illinois', 40.797177,-89.406738, 2]
            ],
            demoCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41,-87),
            map;

            function initialize()
            {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                   zoom: 7,
                   center: demoCenter,
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                 });
            }

            function addMarkers()
            {
                var marker, 
                i,
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                for (i = 0; i < cityList.length; i++) 
                {  
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]),
                        map: map,
                        title: cityList[i][0]
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent(cityList[i][0]);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
                }
            }
            $(document).on("pageinit", "#basic-map", function() {
                initialize();
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.add-markers', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                addMarkers();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQuery mobile with Google maps v3</a> examples</h1>
                <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="add-markers" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Add Some More Markers</a>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks,  this small examples work, but is there a way to do this without using the `$('#map_canvas').gmap` ... syntax? How can I do the exact same thing with global variables for the map and marker? I have tried some thing on my own, but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Hi Erin, I will update my post with a new example in which the jquery-ui-map plugin has been removed. Therefore only the Google Maps API v3 is used. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I've got another follow question to this question linked in this comment, which also addresses global variable question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099351/infowindows-are-not-unique-google-maps-api-v3-jquery-mobile