# InfoWindows are not unique, google maps API v3, jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, jquery-ui-map

I have a simple program where I want the following to happen:

1. Click "Add Some Markers to Map", will show 4 markers with the locations specified in the `cityList` array.
2. Click on a marker and it will open up and infoWindow and display the corresponding index in the `cityList` array.  So if you click on the marker corresponding to `cityList[0]`, it will show you "0" in the infoWindow.

I can add the markers and add the infoWindows, but the content in the infoWindows are incorrect. First of all, they are all the same, and secondly the are displaying the value of the iterator `i` at the end of the loop.

My questions are

1. How can I fix this?
2. I've tried implementing this same code using a global variable for the map and it doesn't work.  Why not? For example, if I replace

```js
function initialize()
{
    $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': city0, 'zoom': 7, 'disableDefaultUI':false });
}
```

with

```js
var map;
function initialize()
{
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {'center': city0, 'zoom': 7, 'disableDefaultUI':false } );
}
```

then the map doesn't even show up when I load the page.

Here is my code:

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps - Google maps jQuery plugin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/min/jquery.ui.map.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var city0 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033,-87.6500523);
    var city1 = new google.maps.LatLng(41,-87);
    var city2 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.5,-87.5);
    var city3 =  new google.maps.LatLng(41.4,-87.2);
    var cityList = [city0, city1, city2, city3];

    function initialize()
    {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': city0, 'zoom': 7, 'disableDefaultUI':false });
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        initialize();
        $('.add-markers').click(function() {
            for(var i=0; i<cityList.length; i++){
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': cityList[i] } ).click(function() {
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': i.toString()}, this);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQuery mobile with Google maps v3</a> examples</h1>
            <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="add-markers" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Add Some More Markers</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="info-page" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">more info v3</a> examples</h1>
            <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                <div id="info_page" style="height:350px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="moreInfo"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The lat example I posted has 2 markers and the info windows are separate. The chicago marker shows chicago and the illinois marker shows illinois. Now if you replace the line infowindow.setContent(cityList[i][0]); with the line infowindow.setContent(i+''); the info window will show the array index. Regarding your question 2, there are many ways to implement maps. In my last example i used only the Google Maps v3 plugin. In the examples that contain the gmap keyword, the jquery-ui-map plugin is used in combination with the Google Map v3. If i'm missing something plz explain.

Comment: Erin, the problem you are mentioning is related to the example with gmap? if yes I could post a new example with the solution. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have found lots of examples like the one you showed using InfoWindows without using gmaps.  But the syntax using the jQuery-ui-map is confusing me.  It would be very helpful if you could post an example here that has multiple markers with unique infoWindows using `gmap`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course. I will post an example with gmap. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see your point. You were right about the problems in creating a list of markers with unique infoWindows using the jquery-ui-maps plugin.

To overcome these problems I'm creating a unique id (id: i) in each $marker definition and the id is equal to the for loop index named i. In the click event I know the correct index from the marker's id and i'm using it to retrieve the correct cityList value.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps - Google maps jQuery plugin</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/min/jquery.ui.map.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033,-87.6500523),
                mobileDemo = { 'center': '41,-87', 'zoom': 7 },
                cityList = [
                    ['Chicago', 41.850033, -87.6500523, 1],
                    ['Illinois', 40.797177,-89.406738, 2]
                ];

            function initialize()
            {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': mobileDemo.center, 'zoom': mobileDemo.zoom, 'disableDefaultUI':false });
            }

            function addMarkers()
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < cityList.length; i++) 
                {
                    var $marker = $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {id: i, 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]), title: cityList[i][0]});
                    $marker.click(function() {
                        $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': cityList[this.id][0]}, this);
                    });
                }
            }

            $(document).on("pageinit", "#basic-map", function() {
                initialize();
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.add-markers', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                addMarkers();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQuery mobile with Google maps v3</a> examples</h1>
                <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="add-markers" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Add Some More Markers</a>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```